# Firebase - push() callback

Tags: callback, firebase, push

Is there any way how to find out when my data were saved in DB using push() method? I wrote following code but it saves data multiple times...

```
db.ref('news').push(opts).then(() => {
    // do smth. (e.g. hide preloader) when data were succesfully saved
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I am not wrong, push() callback should be like this:

```
db.ref('news').push(opts, function(error) {
  if (error)
    console.log('Error has occured during saving process')
  else
    console.log("Data hss been saved succesfully")
})
```